# Loading react native issue on emulator GenyMotion

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react native

`react-native-cli: 2.0.1`
`react-native: 0.55.3`

I was running via 
`react-native run-android`

The screen is always loading the app (Debugger Mode)

NOTE: It was sudden issue, it was working fine till yesterday.
*PC is Restarted several time and also JS server using `kill -9 PID`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've met this error before when I started to programming React Native on Ubuntu.

The reason why you got this error because your Genymotion didn't have same port with local machine.

So here is the solution:

- Open the Developer Menu of mobile app on Genymotion
- Choose the  Debug Server port & port for device
- Set the value `localhost:8081`
- reload the app and enable the Debug. Now you can debug the app.

Cheer!

Comment: Hello, i can login to debugger, still with the same issue with the emulator. Emulator is not loading my app!!

Comment: @prazeev set port to `Developer menu`. Then close debug mode and close the app. Open app again to relaunch the new port. It is simple but you need to do it step by step for getting the launch the app successful.

Comment: Followed with your instruction. IP changed to **localhost:8081**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a problem with the app already installed in your phone. 
Try running :

```
adb uninstall com.yourproject
```

This will install all of your project packages for **all** users on your emulator/phone

Comment: I have uninstalled the project via drag and dropping and also, `adb uninstall com.project` Still same issue

Comment: Have you run .\gradlew clean, deleted build folder. If so could you give us a little bit of code to see what it is supposed to display. Maybe also the routing file if you have one

Comment: Sir, i don't think thats of routing issue, because, if so, emulator should show error!! My issue is, APP IS NOT LOADING!!

Answer (score 0):

Temporary fix:

```
REACT_TERMINAL=<your terminal> react-native run-android
```

in my case with `manjaro + xfce4`:

```
REACT_TERMINAL=xfce4-terminal react-native run-android
```

or puts in your `.bashrc`:

```
export REACT_TERMINAL=xfce4-terminal
```