# emulator stuck at loading from 10.0.2.2:8081,what is issue?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am working on a react-native project and I run it on emulator android(AVD manager)

i have run ***adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081*** at cmd , but still my emulator stuck Whenever i am changing my project and reload emulator!

#### Development Operating System:Windows 10

React Native version: 0.55.4[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50D4w.png)

Comment: What is running at `10.0.2.2`, and can the Android (Emulator) properly route packets to that address?

Comment: i don't know what is running at 10.0.2.2!!, when i am running **react-native run-android** ,it build successful

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by reinstalling the `watchman` package. If you are using mac do this `brew uninstall watchman` and then `brew install watchman`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your 8081 port is already in use.

Try the first solution in here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting

$ sudo lsof -i :8081

$ kill -9

After that,

$ cd YourProject

and

$ npm start

this should help you debugging the packager

Answer (score 2):

```
echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

YEP, THAT'S IT.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue that watchman wasn't able to create the directory in /usr/local/var/run/watchman/-state. I granted access to the parent directory (probably not needed as it likely users system access) then I manually created the directory and re-ran it.

I got the path to the missing directory from the metro terminal window.

Worked fine after that.

Comment: Welcome to SO @GrahamWallace. You should look at the [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page to understand what are the standards of writing an answer here at SO.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of React Native change the port of emulator by somehow but the older not.
   Anyway, please reference to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50406482/5501242) . Then it will help you sort it out.

Cheer!

Comment: i don't find Debug Server port & port for device at android emulator (AVD)

Comment: In emulator, press Ctrl+M to open Developer menu.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue can also relate to watchman, try the following commands (I used them on linux ubuntu)

```
   echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
   echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
   echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

the above commands worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Solution for Ubuntu found here: https://reactnativeforyou.com/android-emulator-stuck-at-loading-from-10-0-2-28081-react-native-issue-fix/

```sh
echo 256 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
echo 32768 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_queued_events
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
pkill node
```