# React native emulator in mac stuck in loading from 10.0.2.3:8081

Tags: android, reactjs, macos, react-native

I am trying to run react-native(android) app on mac os with but it get stuck in white screen with **loading from 10.0.2.2:8081** message at the top.

I am using node version v14.8.0 and npm version is 6.14.7.

How can i resolve this error?

Comment: It has something to do with `watchman`. Check you have the latest version, and try running the `watchman` command and see if it's working. Also, check this question too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51622967/emulator-stuck-at-loading-from-10-0-2-28081-what-is-issue

Comment: I have already tried reinstalling watchman but still no luck